# Is lactate threshold different for different activities and/or muscle groups?

Tags: muscle, cardio, lactate-threshold

Is the adaption resulting from lactate threshold training mainly in the trained muscles, in the cardiovascular system, or both?

If I improve my lactate threshold through one kind of training, recruiting particular muscles, will that improvement transfer to different kinds of activity that involve different muscles?

Comment: The title of your question is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by McPartland, Darren; Pree, Adrian; Malpeli, Robert; Telford, Amanda (2010). Nelson Physical Education Studies For WA. Australia: Nelson

It would probably be muscle specific, before reach lactate threshold, it must first build up in the specific muscles and then is released onto the bloodstream.